# lp/lpr + Lexmark doesn't return indentation after newline

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, cups, printing, printer

I set up CUPS to use my Lexmark MC3224 printer by default, but I have an odd problem: after each newline, the text does not continue at the left edge, but continues at the place where the previous line left off. For example, the text

```
Hello,
World
  Foo
   Bar
```

would not be printed that way, but as

```
Hello,
      World
             Foo
                   Bar
```

Is this an issue specific to the interaction with Lexmark, or is it an issue with my setup? Out of curiosity, I tried using `lpr`, but nothing seems to have changed. Is there an option I have to set for compatibility? Any help would be much appreciated, as printing using LibreOffice every time is very annoying.

Comment: Sounds like a typical line-ending issue.  `\n`, or a "newline" is simple a directive for the cursor (or print head) to move down, while a `\r`, or "carriage return" is a simple directive for the cursor (or print head) to return to the first (i. e. typically leftmost) column.  Different OSs uses different line endings, and the printer doesn't know which OS is sending it a print instruction.  You can probably tell your printer somewhere in its settings what line endings to expect and behave appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! I tried converting the line endings manually, and it printed properly (I didn't think about the fact that, according to Windows, `\n` would simply mean "go down a line"). However, do you know about any docs I might refer to in order to set such an option on the client-side? I share the printer with Windows devices, and would rather not ruin their printing experience.

Comment: You could run your files through `unix2dos` which translates line endings.

Comment: That works for now, especially with an alias, but it would be preferable to set an option in the CUPS settings. I read something about `/usr/lib/lp/` scripts when researching the issue, but couldn't find anything further than that (it was on a thread about HP-UX, so it might not even be related).